# Employee table and need output in the below format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

[image]

I need output in the format below:

```
EMP_NUM,Current_Department_number,Previous_Department_number
```

The start and end date(columns) in the table represents employee has worked in Particular department for specific period of time.

Example : From table Employee 102 has started working in department 10 from Jan 2001 to Jan 2002 and then he moved to department 20 where he worked from Jan 2002 to Jan 2003.

But I need the output like this:

```
EMP_NUM,Current_Department_number,Previous_Department_number
```

Please let me know if you need any other details!

Comment: If employer  worked more than 2 departments, will you only show the first and the last one?

Comment: You've currently got noone working for any department, is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Pelin, If employer worked more than 2 departments then it should show current dept as current department others as previous department

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select emp_num, dept_id as Current_Department_number,
       lag(dept_id) over (partition by emp_num order by start_date) as previous_department_number
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method is to use of `subquery`

```
select EMP_NUM, dept_id as Current_Department_number, 
      (select top 1 dept_id from table 
       where EMP_NUM = t.EMP_NUM and start_date < t.start_date order by start_date) as Previous_Department_number
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it will give current department and previous department:

```
 ;WITH EmployeeCTE AS (
    SELECT EMPID,
    DEPTID = 
        STUFF((SELECT TOP(2)',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), DEPTID )
               FROM EMPDEPT b 
               WHERE b.EMPID = a.EMPID 
               ORDER BY JDATE DESC
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    FROM EMPDEPT a
    GROUP BY EMPID
    )
    SELECT
    EMPID,
    (SELECT Substring(DEPTID, 1, 
    CASE WHEN  CHARINDEX(',', DEPTID ) = 0 then LEN(DEPTID) 
    ELSE CHARINDEX(',', DEPTID) -1 END
    )) as CurrentDept ,
    (SELECT Substring(DEPTID, Charindex(',', DEPTID) + 1, LEN(DEPTID))) as PreviousDept
    FROM EmployeeCTE
```